# My class inherit all params from Thread (TypeError with daemon)

Tags: python

I write a class and want that it inherits all params of Thread.

```
class ThreadExtension(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon)

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self.extension.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

But I have error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I'm confused. If I remove `daemon` from `__init__` - all is fine. Why can not I add `daemon`?

Comment: Note: you don't have to override `__init__` at all if you don't want to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any argument after `*` is required to be listed as a keyword argument. So you have to call the `__init__` as follows

```
threading.Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)
```